# What the last line in custom DRF permission mean

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

This is a snippet from the Django rest framework documentation on **writing custom permissions**. I don't understand the meaning of the last line here:

```
class IsOwnerOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True
        return obj.owner == request.user
```

Comment: It means if the current requesting user is same as the owner of the object that created it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `has_object_permission()` returns `True` or `False` depending in the evaluation of `obj.owner == request.user`